# Maintain multiple git branch while working same files

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I've a requirement where I need to ship two features `X` and `Y`. Both these features touch sames files. Problem is the client may ask to pull out the feature based on timeline and quality. Now there were two approaches I've thought:

1. Create a unified branch, will merge changes for feature `X` and `Y`. Pro: Easy to merge and maintain, Con: Difficult to remove code one of the features asked.
2. Create separate branches and at the end merge to develop. First merge `X` and then resolve huge list of conflicts when merging `Y` to develop. Pro: Easy to remove code, Con: Difficult to merge.

Approach 1

```
                featureTaskOfY
                 /
                /
D(Develop)<----XY<---- featureTaskOfX
```

Approach 2

```
                 
                
D(Develop)<----X<---- featureTaskOfX
       \
        \
         ----------Y<-------featureTaskOfY
```

What can be other ways to resolve it by easier means. Which balances both.

Comment: What language are you developing in?

Comment: developing for android project

Comment: I feel this is more a design problem rather than a git problem. You could define an abstract interface for the target functionality (A+B). Then implement the functionalities either in separate or single file but use the required functionality as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can have both features on the same branch, by committing all the files for feature X in a single commit, and then all Y in another single commit. This way if you had to remove any feature, you could just revert the commit corresponding to the feature.

And you can work on a single branch which saves the Merge conflict hassle.

Comment: Development of feature X and Y will be happening in parallel.